# Matching text field value with array value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I do this: When a user enters the word `dog` into the text field and presses the button, JavaScript looks through a text array which is a list of stuff

```
//key/value?
var dog = ["Good"];
var cat = ["Bad"];
```

and if it matches the word, it prints `Good`.

Comment: you can visit codecademy website they have a lot of good tutorials and they are simple. I think everyone can learn the basics from there. This is not a stack request but you have no idea what you're doing and more important no idea how to do it? Let us see that you started your project/code and where you've stacked so someone can help you

Comment: @alien: your suggestion/telling-off is legitimate, but the underlying question ('how to implement associative arrays in JS?') is as well ....

Answer (score 0):

You want to work with an object with named members.

```
var names = 
{
    'dog': 'good',
    'cat': 'bad'
};
```

supposing you user input is stored in variable userinput and your output should be in variable output can the do

```
for(var membername in names)
{
    if(userinput == membername)
    {
         output = names[membername];
         break;
    }  
}
```